# Is this spam in the C tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, spam

I came across this tag wiki suggested edit for the `C` tag wiki.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4978587

from a 1 point user wanting to add another website into a list of tutorials websites

In section

### Definitive Book Guide

There is a subsection, which is a bit better styled, but basically a list of links:

#### Best website to learn c programming

- http://www.errorless-c.in
- http://www.cprogramming.com
- http://www.cprogrammingexpert.com
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming
- http://www.c4learn.com

The tutorialspoint site has some young women above the fold, smiling at you, but otherwise, I thought, nothing special to see in any of these.

http://www.cprogramming.com wouldn't load

None of these looked like the product of an academic or a generous community member who wants to provide a good C resource without filling it with advertisements.

Would anyone send a friend to any of these to learn C?

But since is my first tag edit, I thought I'd ask before deleting this whole list.

Should the entire subsection **Best Website to learn c programming** be deleted?

**EDIT: It looks like this entire list of tutorial sites was added in edit 44 by user3410837 (deleted) on Mar 13 2014**

Comment: Re: the edit, considering [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24037116/2742805) is their only answer, it doesn't look great...

Comment: The link is not even working. *All links are now re-pointed* to the next URL in the section. Please, can a moderator *teach these reviewers to **pay attention***?

Comment: Well, I could just click "reject", but then there's the other 5 sites.  I suspect none of it is used/useful.

Comment: Seems like spam to me. We could probably automatically ban everyone who tries to add a link ending in `.in` to a tag wiki without losing too much of value...

Comment: most of the wiki is not helpful. Stack Overflow is not a recommendation site so there shouldnt be any links to external resources or tutorials.

Comment: And, unsurprisingly, none of those reviewers have [c] as one of their top tags.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I've rolled back that edit, for two reasons:

- It broke the link section. No actual new link reference had been added, so each link would now load the *next* URL in the list listed.
- The blog post linked is *a blatant copyright infringing copy* (from [this tutorial](http://www.physics.drexel.edu/courses/Comp_Phys/General/C_basics/c_tutorial.html)). It is indeed a spam link, aiming to farm advertisement impressions.

The original section was added in March [via a suggested edit by a since-deleted user](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4330379)<sup>*</sup>; I doubt the reviewers that approved that edit also paid attention. The linked sites either don't load, have throw-away content or are just like the most recent link, [outright copyright-infringing sites](http://www.scribd.com/doc/125071256/Introduction-to-C-Programming-Language).

I've removed the whole section from the tag wiki.

In my opinion, the reviewers that approved these two edits all **should be given a reviewing timeout**. They approved edits that broke the page and failed to check whether or not the links were actually useful.

<sup>*<sub>The suggested edit is credited to anonymous but the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3607013/revisions) shows it was in actual fact a now-deleted user.</sub></sup>

Comment: Give the robo-reviewers a break?

Comment: @devnull: absolutely.

Comment: Perhaps it should require more than 1 point to suggest a tag wiki edit?  It takes 100 rep to edit a CW question according to [privs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).  Anyway that's another question.

Comment: "In my opinion, the reviewers that approved these two edits all should be given a reviewing timeout." - Done.

Comment: "They approved edits that broke the page and failed to check whether or not the links were actually useful." Sadly I have no doubt whatsoever that this is not entirely commonplace.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I wish it were NOT entirely commonplace.  Unfortunately the evidence is that it is.

Comment: @Ben: The checking is not commonplace; the failure to check is :)

Comment: What are the copyright rules regarding links/toturials/blog-posts in tag wikis?

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat: same as for every other post; overt self-promotion or links to posts that have no real value in the context of the post are considered spam. If a link is to a 'C tutorial' with a quality level out of proportion with the author credentials (if there are any) and a portion of the text entered into google shows me *the exact same content* from a reputable source (such as a University physics department for one of these) then we are clearly dealing with spam link, inserted solely for the purpose of attracting traffic for advertisement impressions. That's clearly spam.

Answer (score 6):

> http://www.cprogramming.com wouldn't load
>
> None of these looked like the product of an academic or a generous community member who wants to provide a good C resource without filling it with advertisements.

I don't know what happend to the www subdomain, but http://cboard.cprogramming.com/ is a very nice C/C++ programming community that can deliver what SO cannot: hand-holding and guiding newbies through their C and C++ programming endeavours by people who really know a lot about C and C++.

It follows the same model as SO: once you have an account and are logged in, there is no more advertisements (or at least it was that way the last time I was active there.)

Disclaimer: I'm a former mod of that board.

Comment: The website works again

Comment: *"...a very nice C/C++ programming community that can deliver what SO cannot: hand-holding and guiding newbies..."* We do a **lot** of that on SO, when we're doing things right.